# C++ how can we bind a placeholder to a reference/ref argument when initializing a std::function?

Tags: c++, std-function, stdbind

```
#include <functional>
#include <string>

int fn( int a, int & b ) { return a+b; }

struct Fn_struct {
    std::string name {};
    // std::function<int (int,int&)> my_fn {};
    std::function<decltype(fn)> my_fn {};
};

int main()
{
    Fn_struct my_fn_struct1 {"fn(a,b)", std::function<decltype (fn)> {fn} };
    Fn_struct my_fn_struct2 {"fn(a,b)", {fn} };
    Fn_struct my_fn_struct3 {"fn(a,b)", {std::bind( fn, 1, 2) }};
    auto fn_b = std::bind( fn, 1, std::placeholders::_1 );
    Fn_struct my_fn_struct4 {"fn(a,b)", {std::bind( fn, 1, std::placeholders::_1) }};  // todo: why can't int b be a reference?
}
```

my_fn_struct4 does not compile, due to failure find a constructor for bind.  However if b is not a reference it compiles.

On the other hand fn_b does compile.

Any explanation would be appreciated.

Please don't ask why I want to do this.  I would prefer not to use to use pointers to accomplish this unless entirely necessary.

Comment: Please add the error message

Comment: `{std::bind( fn, 1, 2) }` won't really do what you think neither

Comment: I might propose lambda, but unsure what you want... `[](int a, int&/*ignored*/){ fn(1, a); }`.

Comment: I've managed to compile it with gcc 8.3 when swapped placeholders_1 to placeholders_2 `Fn_struct my_fn_struct4 {"fn(a,b)", {std::bind( fn, 1, std::placeholders::_2) }`

Comment: I've checked this on gcc 5.4 and it also compiles, so it's no change between C++14 and C++17,
curiously, running following snippet 
`int b=3; my_fn_struct4.my_fn(2,b);` results in `1+3`

Comment: Don't use `std::bind`. Use lambdas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::bind( fn, 1, std::placeholders::_1 )` returns an object convertible to `std::function<int(int &)> my_fn{};` because a function with 2 parameters is passed and the first parameter is bound to 1:

```
#include <functional>
#include <string>

int fn( int a, int & b ) { return a+b; }

struct Fn_struct {
    std::string name {};
    std::function<int(int &)> my_fn{};
};

int main()
{
    Fn_struct my_fn_struct4 {"fn(a,b)", {std::bind( fn, 1, std::placeholders::_1) }};
}
```

The line

```
Fn_struct my_fn_struct3 {"fn(a,b)", {std::bind( fn, 1, 2) }};
```

works because

> If some of the arguments that are supplied in the call to g() are not
>   matched by any placeholders stored in g, the unused arguments are
>   evaluated and discarded.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind

Comment: *"`std::bind( fn, 1, std::placeholders::_1 )` returns `std::function<int(int &)>`"* No. a custom callable type.

Comment: You might even notice that `{std::bind( fn, 1, 2) }` *"works"*/compiles.

Comment: @Jarod42 to be honest  I don't know why `Fn_struct my_fn_struct3 {"fn(a,b)", {std::bind( fn, 1, 2) }};` compiles.

Comment: @Jarod42, I'm guessing that the compiler ignores the parameters on the destination because all arguments have been bound/satisfied?

Answer (score 1):

`std::placeholders::_*` works by perfectly-forwarding the types which later takes their place.

So, with `std::function<int(int, int&)>`, `std::placeholders::_1` would be a r-value reference and cannot bind to lvalue reference.

You might use lambda which is IMO clearer (even if it is not clear what you want):

```
Fn_struct my_fn_struct3 {"fn(a,b)",
                         [](int/*ignored*/, int&/*ignored*/){ int b = 2; return fn(1, b); }};
Fn_struct my_fn_struct4 {"fn(a,b)",
                         [](int a, int&/*ignored*/){ return fn(1, a); }};
```

[Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/T5zw9IUIEOnY7vu0)

Note: lambda requires extra variable for `2`.

Comment: thanks for showing the general idea behind using a lambda, which I could not visualize before this, however, I can't get either line to compile.  I suspect it is that lambdas have very mangled function signatures/types?  See:  https://wandbox.orghttps://wandbox.org/permlink/mhQ8KoiQZkQRyV9K

Comment: @GrantRostig: Missing `return`, typo fixed, and link added.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO because alias arg. is 2 ways access so compiler cannot and/or prevent initializing assignment for parameter without permanent reference.
And then it thinks it makes sense and will accept and work if the arg. is qualified by `const`

```
#include <functional>                                                          
using namespace std;                                                            

int fn( int a, const int & b ) {            // const qualifier
  return a+b; }

struct Fn_struct {
    string name {};
    // function<int (int,int&)> my_fn {};
    function<decltype(fn)> my_fn {};
};

int main()
{
    Fn_struct my_fn_struct1 {"fn(a,b)", function<decltype (fn)> {fn} };
    Fn_struct my_fn_struct2 {"fn(a,b)", {fn} };
    Fn_struct my_fn_struct3 {"fn(a,b)", {bind( fn, 1, 2) }};
    auto fn_b = bind( fn, 1, placeholders::_1 );
      // obj names edited
    Fn_struct my_fn_struct4 {"fn(a,b)", {fn_b} }; 
    Fn_struct my_fn_struct5 {"fn(a,b)", {bind( fn, 1, placeholders::_1) }};  

}
```